# How to make the images uploaded by users meet the size required by the design draft through CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

Hello everyone~ I have a problem but my English is not good. I will try my best to express it completely! If the explanation is not clear enough, everyone is welcome to tell me~ The

problem is like this, today there is a block for users to upload photos !
The width and height of this photo after uploading by the user
cannot exceed 360px, the minimum cannot be less than 100px, the
maximum height cannot exceed 200px, and the minimum cannot be less than 100px

.
What I want to ask everyone here is, can this requirement be accomplished only by CSS?
Or can it be accomplished by using JavaScript? But if I use JavaScript, I don't know how to start, because my JavaScript is very poor. I hope I can get your valuable suggestions here, thank you.

I wrote an example. The original picture size is only 50PX in height. How can the height of the photo reach 100PX without affecting the ratio?

```css
.photo{
  width: 360px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit:contain;
  object-position:left center
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <img class="photo" src="https://upload.cc/i1/2021/09/30/s73jb5.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `object-fit: cover;` in css?

Comment: Hello~ I have tried it!
But the designer rejected this method, because if the original image has a width and height of 150px * 50px, but my container is set to 360px*200px,
this will make the 150px*50px photo enlarged to 360px ~200PX but I actually only need to enlarge 50PX to the minimum height of 100PX~ The

description may be a bit confusing, sorry~

Comment: Do you mean a maximum height of 100px? In your scenario if the image can't have a height above 100px the it will only be half the height of the container

Comment: @WEIA Do you mean maximum-width=360px and minimum-height=100px ?

Comment: @Narsingitkampalli
What you mean is right~ This is the requirement of the designer! I
am very troubled at the moment

Comment: @WEIA I hope you know how to use javascript. Below I have written one solution for your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do.

Image should have maximum-width to be 360px and minimum height should be 100px.

And also if you want to add `min-width` and `max-height` you can add in `imageSettings` variable in javascript.

If you have multiple images, simply add `imageContainerForJS` class to `img` parent element.

```js
(()=>{
    let imgContainers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.imageContainerForJS'));
    const imageSettings = {
        "max-width": 360,
        "min-height": 100,
    }
    
    for(let imgContainer of imgContainers) {
        let img = imgContainer.querySelector('img');
        if(!img) continue;
        let imageSource = img.src;
        let image = new Image();

        let maxWidth = imageSettings['max-width'] || null;
        let minWidth = imageSettings['min-width'] || 0;
        let maxHeight = imageSettings['max-height'] || null;
        let minHeight = imageSettings['min-height'] || 0;

        image.onload = function() {
            let width = this.width;
            let height = this.height;
            
            if(maxWidth && width > maxWidth) width = maxWidth;
            if(minWidth && width < minWidth) width = minWidth;
            if(minHeight && height < minHeight) height = minHeight;
            if(maxHeight && height > maxHeight) height = maxHeight;

            imgContainer.style.width = width+'px';
            imgContainer.style.height = height+'px';
        }

        image.src = imageSource;
    }
})();
```

```css
.photo{
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo imageContainerForJS">
    <img class="photo" src="https://upload.cc/i1/2021/09/30/s73jb5.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much~ You seem to have provided me with a solution, although I haven't started to try it!
But I would like to ask about your js writing. I have never seen it, why it was (()=>{ ....} in the beginning ) Such a structure~
instead of function demo(){....}} as I originally thought?

Comment: `(()=>{...})` it will create a new block so you can use `imageSettings` and `imgContainers` variables again outside this block, so you don't need to think which variable used in which file if you write a large code with multiple files. And yes as you to we can create a new block with named function like `function demo(){....}` and call `demo()` but there is a chance to create two same named function, to avoid these misconception we create block or function without any name like `(function() {...})` or `(()=>{...})`

Comment: `(()=>{...})` create function. and `(()=>{...})()` create function with calling

Answer (score 2):

You can use `object-fit:cover` to make your image proportionally expand to fill its container.

Set the container to the dimensions you want, then have the image fill it by setting its width and height be 100%.

By default `cover` will position the image in the centre.

```css
.demo {
  width: 360px;
  height: 200px;
}

.demo .photo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  /*object-position: left center;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <img class="photo" src="https://upload.cc/i1/2021/09/30/s73jb5.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```